How can I find logcat files if I delete them in Android Studio?
What program or code could I use to automatically save my logcat files in Android Studio?
I was doing a testcase and recording the console logs in Logcat, and when I found a bug, I was trying to get the file from Logcat and accidentally hit the delete button. Now my file is gone, and I need to know how to retrieve it if it happens again.

Save Logcat files in Android Studio and prevent accidental deletion, follow these steps:
Create a Script:

Windows: adb logcat -v time > C:\path\to\save\logcat_output.txt
Mac/Linux: adb logcat -v time > /path/to/save/logcat_output.txt

Run the Script: Execute this script before starting your tests to save logs continuously.
Use Logcat Settings: Configure Android Studio to save logs automatically if possible.
File Monitoring: Consider using a file monitoring tool to back up your Logcat file regularly.
This setup will help you avoid losing logs and manage your debugging process.
